# How to remove icon glare in XCode 5 / iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I am using XCode 5 developer preview to create an iOS 7 app. In iOS 7, the glare effect of an icon does not exist anymore. That's fine. But now, when I run an app compiled by XCode 5 on an iOS 6 device (or simulator) I see the glare effect on the icon! The usual ways of disabling glare (editing the App-Info.plist file) don't work anymore.

So my question is: how can I disable the glare effect on iOS 6 in an app compiled by XCode 5?

Side note: I'm using the asset library to configure all the different icon sizes.

Comment: Dont forget xCode5 is under NDA so should not be discussed on a public forum such as here. Also it is still beta so could be worth logging a bug with Apple as this may be an oversight or not yet added

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm desperate :P

Comment: Try asking on http://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As the NDA has been lift, I can tell you the answer:

1. go to Images.xcassets in your Xcode 5 project
2. look for AppIcon
3. select iPhone App iOS 5,6 57pt
4. in the Inspector side bar, tick/untick the "iOS icon is pre-rendered" checkbox as you wish!

[image]

Comment: This method doesn't work when project was created in xcode earlier than 5 version, use @sag answer for that purpose

Answer (score 9):

Add to "***Icon files (iOS 5)***"->"***Primary Icon***" "***Icon already includes gloss effects***" ***Boolean YES*** in **-Info.plist* file of your project (XCode 5)..

Answer (score 0):

*(**Note:** this is based on Xcode 4 knowledge)*

Tick the pre-rendered checkbox next to your app icons in your target settings.

This will remove any effect added to the icon.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That checkbox is no longer present in XCode 5. I understand why: in iOS 7, the glare effect does no longer exist.

Comment: In that case then http://devforums.apple.com/ is your way to go because of the NDA.