# Xcode 5 - Icon pre-rendered effect not working

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

In this project Icon assets catalog not used. I set glow included. But still displayed glow.

Here is plist screenshot:
[image]

Here is Game Icon from AppStore: http://is.gd/Uvuipq

How can I fix Icon glare? Its not required.

Searched in stackoverflow, Here is previous question..none of the answer helped

[How to remove icon glare in XCode 5 / iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145485/how-to-remove-icon-glare-in-xcode-5-ios-7)

[Icon gloss with iOS 6 & Xcode 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034674/icon-gloss-with-ios-6-xcode-5-0)

Anything updated in Xcode 5.1 ?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you see gloss effect in iOS6 springboard? Seems to be you should try to use another key-value pair from info.plist:

[image]

Comment: its ios6+ app, already added this. Please check my updated question with plist screenshot.